# If page = home display this div MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Im very new to MVC so I dont quite know how to go about displaying a div on the home page only. Basically it is a preloader that I dont want to display on any other page other than home.

I usually do this in .NET as follows:

```
      <%if(Request.Url.ToString().ToLower().Contains("default")) {%>
        <div id="PageLoader">
            <div class="PageLoaderInner">
                <div class="LoaderLogo"><img src="/Content/Images/Masterpage/Logo.png" width="127" height="125"/></div>
                <div class="LoaderIcon"><span class="spinner"></span><span></span></div>
            </div>
        </div>
      <%}%>
```

It is also a very basic website that I am making so I have removed the controller name out of the URL, in my case "Pages" so the URL displays /Contact instead of /Pages/Contact

Is there another way do display the div other than looking at the URL? It would be awesome if someone could show me how to do this in the Pages controller as well as "inline" in the HTML.

All the Pages controller displays at the moment is this:

```
namespace WebsiteName.Web.Controllers
{
    public class PagesController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Contact()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks guys.

Comment: Maybe just put the `div` in the `Index` view and no other view?

Comment: The answer is above. Just put that `div` element in your `Index` view.

Comment: I thought about that but the div needs to be at the top of the page below the opening <body>. I could add a ContentPlaceHolder if thats the only way to go about doing it. Thanks.

Comment: Then in master layout use `@RenderSection("SectionName")` and in your `Index` view use this code: `@section SectionName { // code here }` - this should work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to explain a bit what **Rosko** said in the comment with a code

**Layout Page**

```
<div id="body">
        @RenderSection("SectionName", required: false)
        <section class="content-wrapper main-content clear-fix">
            @RenderBody()
        </section>
    </div>
```

**Index Page**

```
@section SectionName{
// your code
}
```

The Section SectionName will be rendered before the Index body and similarly you can redefine the place of the section as well.

Answer (score 4):

You can try this:
Edit: without checking the URL

```
@{if(ViewBag.isHome)
   {
        <div id="PageLoader">
            <div class="PageLoaderInner">
                <div class="LoaderLogo"><img src="/Content/Images/Masterpage/Logo.png" width="127" height="125"/></div>
                <div class="LoaderIcon"><span class="spinner"></span><span></span></div>
            </div>
        </div>
      }
}
```

///Server

```
namespace WebsiteName.Web.Controllers
 {
    public class PagesController : Controller
    {
         public ActionResult Index()
         {
             ViewBag.isHome = true;
             return View();
         }

         public ActionResult Contact()
         {
             return View();
         }
    }
 }
```

Comment: Another valid solution but I think this is not desired one...:)

Comment: Thanks for this smart solution. Good works

Comment: I would recommend using a string instead of boolean to set the home ViewBag, e.g. `ViewBag.isHome = "true";` and check it in the layout using `@if(ViewBag.isHome == "true")`. In this case you won't have to set the `ViewBag.isHome` variable in other controllers.